# Type error despite both instances being floats

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a very simple bit of code that is acting a bit unusual.

```
col1=[0.1,0.2,"x",0.3,0.1]


for x in col1:
    if x=="x":
        lo=col1.index("x")-1
        hi=col1.index("x")+1
        if col1[lo]>col1[hi]:
            col1[lo]="x"
        else:
            col1[hi]="x"
```

Running it returns:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Despite the fact that:

```
col1=[0.1,0.2,"x",0.3,0.1]
lo=col1.index("x")-1
hi=col1.index("x")+1

print(lo)
print(hi)

print(col1[lo])
print(col1[hi])

print(type(col1[lo]))
print(type(col1[hi]))
```

Returns:

```
1
3
0.2
0.3
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
```

Even more unusually, if you swap the `>` to a `<` then the code functions just fine, albeit doing the opposite of what I want it to do.

Any idea what's going on here?

Edit:
Thanks for the comment. Have spotted the problem now.
Was a dumb mistake but had me confused.

Comment: *"despite both instances being floats"* - clearly not. Things like `col1[lo]="x"` seem suspicious, no?

Comment: Try adding a line like this before the one which fails: `print(col1, lo, hi, col1[lo], col1[hi])`

Comment: But it is a float while the test is happening. Also like I said the code runs if the sign is flipped.

Comment: Ok, now I get you. Forgot it was a loop.
Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

col1=[0.1,0.2,"x",0.3,0.1]
The problem is that you are writing to the list while working with it. Do:

```
col1=[0.1,0.2,"x",0.3,0.1]

newcol=col1[:]
for x in col1:
    if x=="x":
        lo=col1.index("x")-1
        hi=col1.index("x")+1
        if col1[lo]>col1[hi]:
            newcol[lo]="x"
        else:
            newcol[hi]="x"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're modifying the list in place. This will work:

```
col1=[0.1,0.2,"x",0.3,0.1]
for x in col1[:]:
    if x=="x":
        lo=col1.index("x")-1
        hi=col1.index("x")+1
        if col1[lo]>col1[hi]:
            col1[lo]="x"
        else:
            col1[hi]="x"
```

Note I make a copy of `col1` at the for loop by using it as `col1[:]`. Generally speaking, I don't like this code, exactly because you're modifying it in place. You should break after you found for `x=='x'` if you sure you're expecting only one such element.

Comment: Only expecting one such element in this instance but it will later include the possibility of more.